# Querying "beaconinfo.getforobserved" after a delay (2-3 days) from when the packets are received from BLE beacon returns NO data & decrypting TLM data

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I am using iBKS 105 BLE beacons from [Accent Systems](https://accent-systems.com/). I am receiving Eddystone data packets as outlined in their [sample code on github](https://github.com/AccentSystems/iBKS-SDK-Android). The beacons are registered on [my project's Google Proximity Beacon Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard).

The primary data fields that I'm concerned with are:

```
- TimestampNanos
- Advertised ID (EID)
- EncryptedTLMData, Salt, IntegrityCheck
```

The advertised data is encrypted, so to fetch the beacon attachment data I use Google Proximity Beacon API's "beaconinfo.getforobserved" HTTP request.

On 21st March '18, I received the following data from the beacon:

```
"timestampNanos" : 201887331447701,
"advertisedEID" : "326846421e0df00d",
"telemetry" : {
    "encryptedDataTLM" : "39769a4b12d45bee0457e83a",
    "salt" : "37fa",
    "integrityCheck" : "01e6"
}
```

Converting it to the "base64" encoding as required by the endpoint:

```
{
    "observations": [{
        "advertisedId": {
            "type": "EDDYSTONE_EID",
            "id": "MmhGQh4N8A0="
        },
        "telemetry": "IAE5dppLEtRb7gRX6Do3+gHm",
        "timestampMs": "8367-07-23T03:47:27.701000000Z"
    }],
    "namespacedTypes": ["*"]
}
```

*On that day when I immediately queried the "getforobserved" request, it correctly returned the beacon attachments saved in the dashboard.* ***But when I query using the same parameters today (24th March), NO data is returned.*** I have not changed any attachments and the beacon is still marked as "ACTIVE" in the dashboard.

- What is the reason for this?
- How can we query "getforobserved" endpoint for cached observations in case there is no internet connection at that time of observation?
- Is it possible to decrypt advertised EIDs locally on an Android device?
- The "getforobserved" endpoint does not return decrypted TLM data. How can we decrypt the TLM data using the Google Proximity Beacon API to get the battery life estimation?

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the Eddystone-EID format which broadcasts an encrypted identifier and requires you to use a trusted resolver to convert the identifier to the meaningful values you mention.

This whole system relies on an accurate clock in the beacon so the beacon's encrypted identifier is in sync with the clock on the resolver side (essentially Google's servers).  **If the clock on the beacon drifts too far, resolution will stop working.**  This is likely what you are seeing.  You can confirm this by re-registering the beacon to see if resolution starts working again.  If this is indeed the problem, you will need to check with the beacon manufacturer to inquire about the stability of the clock, and how long it is expected to resolve properly after registration.  I would hope it would do so for well over one day!  Perhaps you have a bad unit?

While it is possible to build a resolver independent of Google's system (I built one myself for testing during pre-release phase of Edystone-EID), I am not aware of any alternatives available for general use.  In theory you could build one inside your monile app, but again, I am unaware of any publicly available library that does this.

Bottom line: you'll need to use Google's server-based resolvers or build your own.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As advised by you, I'll confirm with the beacon manufacturer about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google server to register the Eddystone-EID packet, is needed to have into account that it works with a strict timing, the beacon and the server use the same clock value and is needed to change it at the same time (a delay of seconds or minutes is allowed, but not much more). In order to resolve the EID correctly with Google server is needed to use recent values of EID (calculated with the actual clock) and an internet connection. If you use EID values of three days ago, Google server will not resolve the EID correctly. This does not mean that Google Server does not allow a delay of days in EID, but the resynchronization can last hours or days. This problem has nothing to do with the drift of the beacon's clock.